# How to define underleftarrow in plain TeX?

Tags: arrows, plain-tex

I want to typeset the lim symbol with an arrow under it (pointing to the left or to the right).

The following works for putting the arrow over lim

```
\def\limleft{\mathop{\overleftarrow{\rm lim}}}

$\limleft_i a_i$
$$\limleft_i a_i$$

\bye
```

but I don't know how to define `underleftarrow`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In analogy with `\overleftarrow`.

The strange vertical kern is because of the “peculiar” bounding box of arrows.

```
\catcode`@=11
% modify \overleftarrow to make \underleftarrow
%\def\overleftarrow#1{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
%      \leftarrowfill\crcr\noalign{\kern-\p@\nointerlineskip}
%      $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}
\def\underleftarrow#1{%
  \vtop{%
    \m@th
    \ialign{##\crcr
      $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\cr
      \noalign{\kern0.4ex\nointerlineskip}
      \leftarrowfill\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\catcode`@=12

\def\limleft{\mathop{\underleftarrow{\rm lim}}}

$$
\limleft
$$

\bye
```

[image]

With `\vbox` you obtain the same reference point as the last item in the vertical box; with `\vtop` the reference point is that of the first item in the vertical material.

Answer (score 5):

You can define `\underleftarrow` analogical like `\overleftarrow` is defined in `plain.tex`.

```
\def\underleftarrow#1{\vtop{\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\cr\noalign{\kern-1.3ex}
   \leftarrowfill\crcr}}}

\def\ulimleft{\mathop{\underleftarrow{\rm lim}}}

% Try this:
$\ulimleft_i a_i$
$$\ulimleft_i a_i$$

\bye
```